# Becoming a microsoft partner organisation

Tags: microsoft

Does anyone know the process of becoming a microsoft partner for an organisation. What the requirements and process are?

Comment: There exist several partnership programs in Microsoft: for resellers, for ISVs, for academic organizations. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: We're a re-seller, getting started was as simple as filling out some forms. I think so long as you have a valid business registration the process is quite painless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I became a Microsoft Partner (atleast I think so, I get the newsletter :) by filling in  some online survery. Then I got to buy Visual Studio and some other tools really cheaply (like $500) so that was nice, not sure if it was some special offer though.

https://partner.microsoft.com/40140448